# where did my dropbox folder go in linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dropbox

I've installed Dropbox before on Mac and Windows and in those installations it asked me where I wanted my dropbox folder, but when I installed it on ubuntu 64 linux it didn't seem to ask that, and I can't find a dropbox folder anywhere in the filesystem.

So, where's my dropbox?

I am a total beginner at linux, there might be something really simple I've missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does default to ~/Dropbox, but if you weren't given a choice of where to put it, my guess is that you haven't finished installing it yet. If memory serves, on Ubuntu, it's not enough to simply download and install the package; you need to choose it from the GNOME menu, and the first time you do so, it'll go through the steps for configuring it, and so on. Did you do all that?

Comment: that seemed to be it, on closer inspection there was a dropbox logo sitting on the toolbar at the top of the desktop that i needed to click to finish the install

Answer (score 1):

Last time I installed Dropbox it was at `~/Dropbox`.

Comment: doesn't seem to be there

Answer (score 0):

When I run dropbox, it displays an icon in the systray. Right click, choose "preferences". Find the location of the dropbox folder.

Answer (score 0):

I did the Dropbox "build from source" option on Ubuntu Quantal and had to take some extra steps before it would run. First got some libraries and the Python docutils package (won't elaborate on this since not relevant to the question). Then I ran from the terminal:

```
~/nautilus-dropbox-1.4.0$ ./dropbox start -i
```

This downloaded the Dropbox daemon and set up `~/Dropbox` with a bunch of dialog boxes, buttons, and wizards.

The systray icon mentioned in other answers did not appear until after running the shell command above.

Answer (score 0):

After I installed dropbox using:

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-dropbox
```

I used:

```
dropbox start -i
```

The deamon downloads, and installs, after which I got a ~/Dropbox folder.